# ora-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I am having problem with my query...

This one works:

```
  select name, bday, address, dbms_random.value(1, 100) as joker
    from employee 
order by joker asc
```

But when I try to get what I want using either the 'where' and group/having clause, I am getting a ora-00904 (invalid identifier) ERROR..

e.g.

```
  select name, bday, address, dbms_random.value(1, 100) as joker 
    from employee 
   where joker>5 
order by joker asc

  select name, bday, address, dbms_random.value(1, 100) as joker
    from employee 
group by name, bday, address 
  having joker > 5 
order by joker asc
```

What could be my problem here and how can i query using the joker column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
Select * from
(select name, bday, address, dbms_random.value(1, 100) as joker 
from employee)
where joker>5 
order by joker asc
```

Comment: tnx michael, it worked, do you know what kind of sql format is this? and why is it reformatted like that? is it because i got the new joker column? tnx

Comment: yup got the same question as vc74 .. ;(.. is this kind of query compatible with mysql, sqlite.. etc? tnx

Comment: @user415881, will works if you replace function dbms_random.value for mysql to rand(), for sqlite to random()

Comment: @michael , no what i meant was, with your sql.. why is it formed that way, instead of mine.. in your sql you used .. select * (select * from ???) .. just wondering why it should be done this way.. ;(

Comment: sorry your sql is "select * from (select * from somethin)"

Comment: @user415881, because you can't reference in where clause to aliased column. instead of 'joker > 5' you have to use 'dbms_random.value(1, 100) > 5'

Comment: ok tnx michael... last question. ;) ... is that alias rule about using it in a where clause (..like your sql) applies to all sql compliant rdbms? many tnx

Comment: @user415881, probably - yes :)

Comment: @VC 74: This works because you can sort/group/filter by an expression, but you can't sort/group/filter by the name you give the expression in the same query.  By nesting the query with the call to DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, the alias JOKER is available to the ORDER BY clause in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

GOOD.This works because you can sort/group/filter by an expression, but you can't sort/group/filter by the name you give the expression in the same query. By nesting the query with the call to DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, the alias JOKER is available to the ORDER BY clause in the outer query. –